# How to define a type that can hold a uintptr_t or a uint32_t without a union?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, typedef

How can I define a type `uintptr` such that it can hold at least a `uint32_t` and a `uintptr_t`, without resorting to a union?

Were `sizeof()` allowed in the preprocessor, this would accomplish what I want:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#if sizeof(uint32_t) > sizeof(uintptr_t)  // unlikely, but the standard allows it
    typedef uint32_t uintptr;  
#else
    typedef uintptr_t uintptr;
#endif
```

It is extremely likely that `uint32_t` will be smaller if not equal to `uintptr_t` but the standard makes no guarantee.  That said, such a platform would be very rare, so for now I've solved this by just having the following:

```
static_assert(sizeof(uint32_t) <= sizeof(uintptr_t), "Yikes");
typedef uintptr_t uintptr;
```

Comment: But the type `uintptr_t` should be large enough to hold any pointer ot integer type on your platform. Why do you want to create your own type-alias? What is the *real* and *actual* problem that you need to solve that the standard generic types doesn't provide? Consider making *descriptive* type-aliases (something that describes the semantic meaning of the type) instead of generic integer types.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - the real problem is that I have a `userData` variable in a physics contact solver that I want a user of my library to be able to stick a uint32 or a pointer into.  My specific goal is to provide a generic type for them

Comment: Then use just plain `uintptr_t`. As I mentioned, it can contain a pointer *or* the largest integer possible on your system (which means it will definitely fit a 32-bit integer). Possibly create a type-alias with a descriptive name like `using userdata_type = uintptr_t;`, and then use `userdata_type` when needed. Yes `uintptr_t` is optional, but you will have a very hard time to find a compiler and system where it's not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for the preprocessor to get such an alias. It's a simple use case for the standard library's type traits

```
using uintptr = std::conditional_t<(sizeof(uint32_t) > sizeof(uintptr_t)),
                                   uint32_t, uintptr_t>;
```